# Why can I not save a page rendered as a PDF?

Tags: pdf, save, visualforce

I have rendered a visualforce page as a pdf.  It displays perfectly in the browser and I can zoom, scroll and print it.  Why can I not save it?  Neither the save button, not the Save As... option on the context menu work.

Comment: Which browser? What does `Ctrl+S` do? Do you have any plugins installed in the browser that "hijack" the pdf (so they fire a viewer tool instead of normal "Save As" prompt that should happen when browser encounters such document).

Answer (score 0):

Probably PDF was incorrectly embed into HTML content. Should be something like: 
`<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="http://..." type="application/pdf">` on your page. You can install Adobe web plugin. It works fine. Plugin's save menu occurs in the right bottom corner.[image: Screen]

Comment: The page starts as HTML, it's not embedded into a page.  I'm simply using visualforce's feature of renderas="pdf".  The menu you are referring to is the one from which the 'save as' option does not work.